# Get sender (button) from child window

Tags: silverlight, button, childwindow, sender

I was generate the button through code. and with the button i got one method to call up the child window in silverlight.

```
   private void btnXX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        SlotMaker slotMaker = new SlotMaker();
        slotMaker.Show();
    }
```

while the child window pop up, may i know how could i get the sender.content ?? from the child window

Comment: Do you mean the button text? Or do you have more complex content in the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `SlotMaker` constructor to

```
 public DateTime SlotDateTime {get; private set; }

 public SlotMaker(DateTime slotDateTime)
 {
      SlotDateTime = slotDateTime;
      InitializeComponent();
      // Modify some display using value of SlotDateTime
 }
```

Then in your button click

```
private void btnXX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{     
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DateTime dateTime = btn.Tag; // OR = DateTime.Parse(btn.Tag)     
    SlotMaker slotMaker = new SlotMaker(dateTime);     
    slotMaker.Show();     
}
```

Use the button Tag property to place a string in your Xaml that easily parses as .NET DateTime or use code to assign an actual `DateTime` to the Tag property.